# Isolating the name of the final directory in a path?

Tags: bash

I have a variable that contains a file path, like so:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bender/
```

What I need to do is create another variable and set it to the value of the final directory (bender), without the trailing slash. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the standard `basename` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/basename.html):

```
my_new_variable="$(basename /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bender/)"
```

(Despite the phrase "non-directory portion" in the first line of the documentation, it will indeed return `bender`.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way; with regex; just for kicks :)

```
[[ '/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bender/' =~ .*\/(.*)\/ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```